# Calculating min and max from Scale Factor and Effective Range

Tags: calculus

I am given a scale factor and an effective range and I need to calculate the maximum and minimum number for that range. I am quite confused by my results.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
ScaleFactor = 2^-18
EffectiveRange = +-1.9x10-3 (seconds)
```

I thought that the calculation was:

```
ans = ScaleFactor & numberWithinEffectiveRange
```

i.e

```
2^-18 * 1.9e-3 =
```

For the effective range this gives a result of `+-7.2479248046875e-09`

Now this is all well and good but I have some example values given, a selection of these are (in seconds):

```
1.5258789e-4 
-3.846945e-5
etc
```

therefore, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your examples, you give us only the answers but leave out the scale factors and effective ranges that lead to those answers. Please supply the full information, then we may be able to help you. As it is now you tell us far too little.

Comment: The scale factor and effective range is at the top. I don't understand how the given values fit between those.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: I think im being stupid - the given values are between the range of +-1.9E-3, I think that's all it is.